# Microsoft Edge Cache Data

Tags: privacy, windows-10, microsoft-edge

On CCleaner in Windows 10, there are options for Microsoft Edge, which I do not use for browsing the web. Deselecting the option to clean for MS Edge significantly speeds up the process, but I am wondering if even though I am not using Edge, Windows is using it somehow to store data that I may want removed for privacy.

Should I leave it included in the cleaning, or leave it out?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a security professional, neither am I smart in this area. However, Cherlynn Low wrote an article that may help. It is called "How to Disable or Enable Cookies on Edge Browser." Here is the link: http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-enable-cookies-edge-browser

Now, my answer to your question. If you are running Windows, then you can can bet that Microsoft is collecting data whenever you are connected to the internet. It may not be personally identifying information, but it does pull from your computer to keep it updated. That said, Edge is related to Microsoft, so while it may not directly "store" other browser information, the parent company does.

Case in point: If you are not using Edge, then it is not directly collecting cookie data. However, *it can,* but only if you allow it.